# VBA in Excel. Generating a PivotTable and hiding subtotals

Tags: excel, vba

I created a way to generate a pivot table on a new worksheet using information from a worksheet named "Log" and then format it into tabular view with no subtotals. The code is even successful at hiding the subtotals, but I'm getting runtime error 1004 unable to set the Subtotals property of the PivotField class when the SetPivotTableOptions function runs.

This is the function where the the error occurs

```
Sub SetPivotTableOptions(pt As PivotTable)
    ' Set PivotTable layout options
    pt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16" ' You can change the style as needed
    pt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

    ' Set subtotal options
    Dim ptField As PivotField
    For Each ptField In pt.PivotFields
        If ptField.orientation = xlRowField Or ptField.orientation = xlColumnField Then
            ptField.Subtotals(1) = False ' Do not show subtotals
        End If
    Next ptField
End Sub
```

Comment: I solved it. Removing the "Or ptField.orientation = xlColumnField" check from the if statement elminated the problem.